# UITabBarController item with different width than others

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitabbarcontroller

is there a way to give one tabbaritem in UITabBarController more width then the others.

by default they are all sized the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do that. Size properties for an UITabBar aren't available for us, simple mortals.

It's more work, but you could create your own custom view instead of an UITabBar.

Comment: thank you. i "hacked" it once for custom images in the tab bar. but there doesnt seem to be a method for resizing the baritem.